# Run same exe twice

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
foreach(string fileName in chunkFiles)
{
    p = GenerateProcessInstance();
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} false {2}", fileName, Id, logName);
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    sent += p.ExitCode;
}
```

What I want to do is if I have at least 2 chunks to run the EXE with 2 instances. My only problem is that I have `WaitForExit`. I am using this because I need a parameter returned from the EXE.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Look up threading. This is too sizeable to place in a single answer.

Comment: If each call/iteration is dependent on the previous result, you cannot parallelize it... you need to change the processes or how you use the results if you want to be able to do so.

Comment: @JeffMercado What makes you think that the two processes are dependent on each other?

Comment: @Servy: I guess after looking at his code again, I suppose you're right.  I just have this feeling that `sent` and `GenerateProcessInstance()` are linked somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler for Exited to handle the return value, like so

```
foreach(string fileName in chunkFiles)
{
    p = GenerateProcessInstance();
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} false {2}", fileName, Id, logName);
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
    p.Start();
}

protected void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var p = (Process)sender;
    // Handle p.ExitCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start all of the process in a loop and then wait on all of them in another loop:

```
var processes = new List<Process>();
int sent = 0;

foreach (string fileName in chunkFiles)
{
    Process p = GenerateProcessInstance();
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} false {2}", fileName, Id, logName);
    p.Start();
    processes.Add(p);
}

foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    p.WaitForExit();
    sent += p.ExitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunExe))
    t.Start
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunExe))
    t2.Start
}

public void RunExe()
{
    foreach(string fileName in chunkFiles)
    {
        p = GenerateProcessInstance();
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} false {2}", fileName, Id, logName);
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        sent += p.ExitCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's rather expensive to start up two threads just to wait on each; you only need the single main thread to wait on all of the processes.  It's as simple as starting all of the processes before waiting on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that at least sometimes when you start two instances of an application, or start an instance of an application when one is already running, WaitForExit and Exited event don't work. If you look closely enough you'll see that the whole Process object goes haywire (and becomes useless) when you try to have multiple instances of the same application. I had to design a workaround that didn't rely on Process object.

Comment: This is just wrong.  It works just fine.  If it wasn't working for you then it was either because you were using it incorrectly, or because there was a problem with the application you were running not working with parallel instances.

Comment: It's possible. Although I wasn't expecting Acrobat Reader to have problems running parallel instances. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the method used was:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
                                    chunkFiles,
                                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
                                    chunk =>
                                    {
                                        //create new paralel process - count limited to MaxDegreeOfParallelism
                                        Process p = ProcessManager.GenerateProcessInstance();
                                        p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", chunk, Id, logFileName, infoFileName);
                                        p.Start();
                                        p.WaitForExit();
                                        sentEmails += p.ExitCode;
                                    }
                                );
```

Comment: This will probably work, but you do not need parallelism to start two processes. Just start the first and the second process and then wait for both to exit. All this can be done on a single thread.

Comment: You might have right but: 1. i dont know the number of processes i have to start and 2. there is a speed difference between them. The speed is all i need to improve here.